# Display lottiefiles in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, lottie

I had 4 fragments in my viewpager, I tried to dispaly a lottiefile, the first one it works with animation but the second one not animated, the viewpager load 2 fragments in the same time, so my question there's any way to prevent viewpager to load only the visible fragment to have the animation ? I tried `setUserVisibleHint` but it's **deprecated**

my fragment code (I'm on AndroidX) :

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


        public PlaceholderFragment() {
            //
        }


        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);
            TextView sectionLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            TextView sectionDetails = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_details);
            LottieAnimationView img = (LottieAnimationView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_img);


            String[] titles = new String[]{getActivity().getString(R.string.onboarding_explore),getActivity().getString(R.string.onboarding_connect),
                    getActivity().getString(R.string.onboarding_notified), getActivity().getString(R.string.onboarding_create)};
            String[] details = new String[]{getActivity().getString(R.string.onboarding_explore_desc),getActivity().getString(R.string.onboarding_connect_desc)
                    , getActivity().getString(R.string.onboarding_notified_desc), getActivity().getString(R.string.onboarding_create_desc)};


            int[] bgs = new int[]{R.raw.explore, R.raw.connect
                    ,  R.raw.notifications ,  R.raw.places};
            img.setAnimation(bgs[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1]);
            img.playAnimation();
            sectionLabel.setText(titles[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1]);
            sectionDetails.setText(details[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1]);

            return rootView;
        }


    }
```